# The Wordpress Loop doesn't work when using RewriteRule

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am using .htaccess RewriteRule on my page. When user goes to

```
/news
```

RewriteRule actually loads

```
/?nav=news
```

On that page, I use The Wordpress Loop to show recent posts

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

When accessing this page directly from **/?nav=news**, The Loop shows posts. However, when I access the page from **/news** (using RewriteRule), I get no results.

What could cause this?

The actual RewrirteRule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^news\/?$ ?nav=news [L]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to inform wordpress' that these two addresses mean the same using [WP redirect API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). The way you're doing WP doesn't know that `/news` is the same of `/?nav=news`.

Try adding this code to your theme

```
function custom_rewrite_news() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^news/?', 'index.php?nav=news', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_news');
```

In the dashboard go to Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried to put your code into functions.php in my theme folder, Saved Changes in Permarlinks tab and it still doesn't work. And when I open the .htaccess file, the rule is not inserted there.

Comment: Okay, so I have tried to put it that RewriteRule into htaccess by myself and it works. Not sure if the function add_rewrite_rule has to do something with it?